# Create a table dynamically using for loop in .html()

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I am new to JQuery so don't really know how to proceed ahead . I need to create an html structure (table ) dynamically using $(this).html (..create table...).
Below is my pseudo code.

```
$(this).html('<table>for(var a=0;a<NoteCount;a++){<tr><td><div id = "NotePadTextArea">NoteArrayVal[a]</div></td></tr>}</table>'
);
```

NoteArrayVal is an array which already has values in it. 
How to go ahead with this kind of design?
Please help.

Comment: Start by posting expected result, at least

Comment: means you need create multiple table or single dynamic table with for attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create td and text nodes within loop. This code creates only 2 td, so only 2 are visible. Example:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');
    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: @nsingh can you mark it as an aswer and upvote. thanks